# How to push image of springboot project on docker hub

Tags: spring-boot, docker, gradle, dockerfile, build.gradle

I am following this [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/ops/docker-push-image-to-private-repository) to push my jar file of springboot project to docker hub i.e
https://hub.docker.com/

project structure looks like

[image]

Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:11-jre-slim

COPY build/libs/currency-exchange-service-0.0.2.jar /app/currency-exchange-service-0.0.2.jar

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["java", "-jar", "/app/app.jar"]
```

build.gradle looks like

```
plugins {
id 'java'
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.3'
id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
id 'com.bmuschko.docker-remote-api' version '7.2.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.docker-remote-api'

import com.bmuschko.gradle.docker.tasks.image.DockerBuildImage
import com.bmuschko.gradle.docker.tasks.image.DockerPushImage
import com.bmuschko.gradle.docker.tasks.container.DockerCreateContainer
import com.bmuschko.gradle.docker.tasks.container.DockerStartContainer

task buildDockerImage(type: DockerBuildImage) {
    inputDir = project.projectDir
    tags = 'sparsh610/currency-exchange-service-0.0.2.jar'
}

task pushDockerImage(type: DockerPushImage) {
    dependsOn buildDockerImage
    imageName = 'sparsh610/currency-exchange-service-0.0.2.jar'
}

task createDockerContainer(type: DockerCreateContainer) {
    dependsOn pushDockerImage
    imageName = 'sparsh610/currency-exchange-service-0.0.2.jar'
    portBindings = ['8080:8080']
}

task startDockerContainer(type: DockerStartContainer) {
    dependsOn createDockerContainer
    targetContainerId { createDockerContainer.getContainerId() }
}

group = 'com.learning.microservice'
version = '0.0.2'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "2023.0.0")
}


dependencies {
    implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-observation'
    implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-tracing-bridge-otel'
    implementation 'io.opentelemetry:opentelemetry-exporter-zipkin'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop'
    implementation 'io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-spring-boot2'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'com.h2database:h2'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

When I am executing task `startDockerContainer`, I am facing issue that

> Could not set unknown property 'tags' for task ':buildDockerImage' of
> type com.bmuschko.gradle.docker.tasks.image.DockerBuildImage

Please help

Comment: try using `images` property instead of `tags`